# export class on new files not working (react native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to build an app and it was working but for some reason now everytime I try to export something it no longer works (stays greyed out).

- I have copy and pasted a page and just change the file name and the export class still stays greyed out.
- I have deleted the node folder, cleared the cache, and reinstall the cache. Still won't work
- Created a new file in the screen and component folder, copy pasted a working page (screen file to a screen file & component file to component file). The export class still stays greyed out.

example of a button component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Dimensions} from 'react-native';


export default function Timer(props) {
    return(
        <View style={styles.Button}>
            <View>
                { props.children }
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    Button: {
        height:31,
        width: 87,
        borderRadius: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#E0F7EF',
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center', /* center items vertically, in this case */
        alignItems: 'center',    /* center items horizontally, in this case */
    },
})
```

Example of a screen component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { NavigationActions, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import{ ImageBackground, Dimensions, View, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, TextInput, Picker } from 'react-native';
import { SimpleLineIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Container, Header, Content, Card, CardItem, Body, Text } from 'native-base';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons, FontAwesome, MaterialIcons, Ionicons} from '@expo/vector-icons';


import Strings from '../utils/Strings';

var styles = require('../../assets/files/Styles');
var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

//NAVIGATION AT TOP
export default class Cardio extends Component {
static navigationOptions = {
  title: `${Strings.ST201}`,
};

  navigateToScreen = (route) => () => {
    const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName: route,
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
  }



  render () {
    return (

<Container style={styles.background_general}>

<ScrollView>

<View style={{flexDirection:'column', backgroundColor: '#000000', height: height * 0.25}}>
<ImageBackground
      source={require('../../assets/images/header.jpg')}
      style={{flex: 1, width: null, height: null}}>
</ImageBackground>
</View>


<View style={styles.cardslayout}>


    <TextInput
        style={styles.CommentBox}
        placeholder = 'sets'
        returnKeyType="done"

    />
    <TextInput
        style={styles.CommentBox}
        placeholder = 'Reps'
        returnKeyType="done"
    />
</View>

    <View>
   <TextInput />
    </View>


    <View style={styles.cardslayout}>
        <Content horizontal={true}>
            {/*Bike*/}
            <Card>
                <CardItem style={styles.card}>
                    <Text>
                        <MaterialIcons name="directions-bike" size={32} color="white"/>
                    </Text>
                </CardItem>
            </Card>

            <Card>
                <CardItem style={styles.card}>
                    <Text>
                        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="run-fast" size={32} color="white"/>
                    </Text>
                </CardItem>
            </Card>

            <Card>
                <CardItem style={styles.card}>
                    <Text>
                        <Ionicons name="ios-walk" size={32} color="white"/>
                    </Text>
                </CardItem>
            </Card>


        </Content>
    </View>

    {/*END OF CUSTOM INPUT*/}
</ScrollView>
</Container>
    )
  }

}
```

This is what I mean by it being grayed out. 
This is a  custom button file in the component folder.

You can see the export default function working in the custom button file. Now am going to create a test file and copy and paste the same code into it and simply change the function name. Now before I change the function name the "export default function" turns grey but I change the name to reduce confusion here.

[image: You can see the export default function working in the custom button file. Now am going to create a test file and copy and paste the same code into it and simply change the function name. Now before I change the function name the "export default function" turns grey but I change the name to reduce confusion here.]

[image: This is the same code copy and pasted from the custom button file but changed the function name to testing]

Comment: what do you mean by "stays greyed out"? Can you show us where you've used `Timer`?

Comment: so the component gets imported but it is greyed out? ```backgroundColor: '#E0F7EF',```?

Comment: I'm trying to build the timer as a screen or component.you know when you import something but hasn't been called yet so in the ide it has a greyed out color. That's what I mean. Like not being recognized. So if I copy and past the code from a different screen file into the timer screen everything gets recognized except the export turns grey and when I go to a different screen and call it, the page won't load.

Comment: @LonelyCpp I edited my post and added 2 pictures for better understanding. Please let me know if there is any more information. For some reason it is still not working.